# How to prevent Ipod Touch Application from going to sleep

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

I am building an application for the ipod touch that needs to run for several time (like an alarm clock). I would like to prevent the ipod touch from going to sleep unless the use manually exit the application. Is this possible with the current SDK?

Comment: check this link...http://cocoabugs.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-to-aviod-application-going-to-sleep.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can disable the sleep mode:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```

Comment: This one is right but "sometimes" , I noticed that it does not work (even with such settings, the iphone goes to idle :/) . It's not 100% reproducable, I don't know in which cases it occurs (I was on 3.0 when I noticed that), but if someone has also noticed that and if there's a known way to work around it... :/

Answer (score -1):

As kharrison says...

But read-up on what Apple has to say about it here: [iPhone Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationEnvironment/ApplicationEnvironment.html)

For your use-case I think you should consider dimming the screen after a few seconds to minimize power consumption. Also if it is an alarm clock, not to keep the user awake all night:)

Comment: Apple does not allow you to dim the screen.